# Can a magnetic lock be negated or overcome by a stronger electro magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits

Magnetic locks seem to be fairly standard on modern buildings. Is it, though, possible to negate a magnetic lock my placing an oppositely-polarized, strong electromagnet across from the magnets on the inside that, upon activation, would both repel the indoor magnets, and attract the material of the door (assuming metal), effectively opening the locked doors? If so, I feel this would be a pretty big disadvantage when compared to a traditional mechanical lock. Not that a powerful and portable electromagnet is necessarily a readily available thing, but...

Comment: Here is the link to ESE question http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6031/can-a-magnetic-lock-be-negated-or-overcome-by-a-stronger-electromagnet